# Copying schema of Postgis or Spatialite DB to blank one

Tags: postgis, spatial-database, spatialite

I want to copy a **Postgis or Spatialite DB sctructure** (features, tables) to a **blank DB**. **In ArcGIS** i can easily handle it by using **XML Workspace Document**. Fisrtly extact it from a **Geodatabase** and than import it to **blank/empty/new** whatever you say. By the way the **stucture of first DB copied to second DB (without data)**. Features (point, line, polygon etc), tables comes with this XML document. So how can i do this for **Postgis or Spatialite DBs** (opensource dbs). **(I dont want data just structure.)**

Comment: Are you copying a generic PostGIS database structure, or one that uses ArcSDE/ArcServer to manage data?

Comment: Yea i wanna copy DB structure and i am not using ArcSDE.

Answer (score 4):

In spatialite, you could just make a copy of the sqlite file, then open it up, and drop all data from all tables. (and run vacuum full afterwards)

Comment: Thank you, it looks like a solution but a little bit primitive solution.

Answer (score 3):

For Postgres use `pg_dump` whith appropriate options (notably `--only-schema`) to dump the database structure. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-pgdump.html for documentation.

pg_dump writes a dump file which can be transferred to whatever computer you want and then be read back in with `psql` and it's `-f` switch.

Answer (score 0):

For sqlite/spatialite you may want to try

SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master;

and redirect the output to a sql-script (text) file.
Afterwards you can run the script to create a new database.

I have not tried it, though